# Magento 2.2.5: How to make the catalog product image as required?

Tags: magento2, product-images, required

I want to make catalog product image as required in magento2.2.5

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: explain briefly

Comment: I want to make the catalog product image as required field in Magento2 admin catalog->product